static_assert a non-constexpr expression
Is there a way to require the compiler to prove a property of a runtime expression, similar to static_assert but without the requirement that the expression be constexpr?
A trivial case would be something like this:
unsigned f(unsigned i) {
    if (i == 0)
        return 1;
    static_assert(i != 0);
    return i > 0 ? i + 20 : i + 30;
}

This fails to compile because i is not a constant expression, which makes sense. When compiling this function without the static_assert (https://godbolt.org/z/o3KjYGTGr), it is clear that the compiler understands that i is not 0 at optimization level -O2. So is there a way to require the compiler to prove that i is not 0, and abort compilation if it cannot do so?
A practical case for using this is when there is a significant amount of code between the test and the eventual use of the value, without the overhead of a runtime check:
if (i == 0)
    return;
// many lines of code
// assert that i != 0 here
function_that_requires_a_nonzero_arg(i);


Do note that the only reason the compiler does the optimization is that it can prove the code is only called with the compile time value of 5.  If you use a runtime value then the compiler cannot make that optimization: https://godbolt.org/z/GTbsnKvco

In that example, the compiler still generates code to unconditionally add 20 rather than 20 or 30 based on some condition. So the compiler must know that on the last line of f, the condition i > 0 is true for all inputs to f.

That is because the parameter type is unsigned so you can't have a negative value.

The branch is there when i is an int: https://godbolt.org/z/hq6hPGceE

That's because when i is an int, i != 0 does not imply i > 0. Change either line 2 to if (i > 0) or the condition on line 5 to i == 0 and the condition disappears. https://godbolt.org/z/4zEeEhKsW

"a property of a runtime expression, similar to static_assert but without the requirement that the expression be constexpr?"  - I don't get the requirement. "The property"  that makes a static_assert different from a regular runtime assert is that it fires on a constant expression (and causes a hard compilation error). What other property do you find differentiate the two? (other than the opt-in/out nature of asserts)

Are you looking for some kind of formal code verification? You can introduce a type like ValueNotZero that is guarantees to hold a value that is non-zero and then pass that type instead of UINT. That type of yours will of course do a runtime check in its constructor, but that's how it is. It is impossible to guarantee at compile time that dynamic value (entered from terminal for instance) has a particular property w/o runtime check.

Thinking a bit more of what you asked it seems that you want a compiler to prove that at you "dynamic static assert" the value can not be X (where X is 0 in your case). No, there is no general way to achive that of course (it's a halting problem). But as I said you can play with types in the same way as for example you can guarantee char will never hold value==300

Yea, there's no way to prove every case. I was hoping that there is a mechanism to prove some subset of those cases. I guess types are the closest thing to that at compile time.

this is two part,

how to make sure a runtime variable always satisfies a condition.

use assert which is used to test runtime conditions only in debug mode so no overhead in release mode, in later C++ standards we should get contracts, which is a more C++ standard way, while asserts are inherited from C, if you want to enforce it even in release mode then you can create your own assert that throws an exception or calls std::terminate

how to tell the compiler to do optimizations based on a condition that is always true

you use assume attribute C++23, which tells the compiler to optimize for an expression always being true.
compilers don't generally test that runtime conditions will always be true, this is only an optimization opportunity with LTO or whole-program optimization, some static analyzers can prove some conditions by looking into the entire code-base, but compilers work on a translation-unit basis.

I know that I can use a runtime check, but the main point of my question was asking how to check it at compile-time to avoid having an impact on performance. Though I suppose if the compiler knows that the condition is true at compile time, then it will remove the runtime check anyway since it's a no-op.

assume is the opposite of what I'm looking for. I'm not looking for increased performance based on some condition, but compile-time safety without reducing performance. The case I'm interested in is within a single translation unit. Inside a single function for example - there is no need to analyze anything outside f to know that i != 0 on the last line.

@TheBicPen an assert + assume should do what you want, without the "fail at compile time", unfortunately this is what the compilers we have nowadays can do, static analyzers could check that the condition will be satisfied, but you'll have to write your own clang static analyzer checks.

I see. I was really hoping there would be a way to do this at compile-time, but I guess a runtime check is better than nothing. Though I assume that if I add an assert, the compiler would be smart enough to know that the condition being asserted is true from that point, without having to explicitly tell it with [[assume()]]

@TheBicPen asserts are removed in release mode, so you need an assume there if you must have an optimization based on it, as for static analysis checks there is something like clang nonnull for pointers
